# Formatting an array of float values in Numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy

The function `values[(values<=0).argmin():] = 0` turns from the nth element to the last elements values into zeroes if the number is below 0 as seen in the `Int array` output. however when the array elements are floats the arrays are automatically converted into zeroes in the `float array` output. How can I fix this?

Float array

```
Numbers = np.array([123.6 , 123.6 ,  123.6, 110.3748 ,  111.6992976, 102.3165566,  97.81462811])
Numbers[(Numbers>=-50).argmin():] = 0
```

Output

```
[ 10   3 -20   0   0   0]
```

Int array

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([123 , 123 , -123.6,  110,  111])
values[(values<=0).argmin():] = 0
```

Output:

```
[123 , 123 , 0,  0,  0]
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and what does the first output represent?

Comment: Look at `values` before doing the 0 insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT:

Try these 2 methods, one is in place assignment to the NumPy view and the other creates a fresh array to be assigned to another variable -

```
#Method 1 (Inplace assignment)
Numbers[(Numbers<=0).cumsum(dtype=bool)] = 0

#OR

#Method 2 (Not inplace)
np.where(~(Numbers<=0).cumsum(dtype=bool), Numbers, 0)
```

**Explanation -**

1. The bool array that returns `[F, F, F, T, F, F, F]` can be seen as an array of 1s and 0s. Doing a cumsum ends up propogating the first T to the subsequent elements.
2. This, therefore, turns the array as `[F, F, F, T, T, T, T]` which can now be used with just `boolean indexing` and set the view to 0 OR `np.where` to fetch original elements or 0 based on reversing the boolean with `~`
3. Advantage here is that if your array is just composed of False, meaning no element meets the condition, it just returns the original `Numbers` itself, instead of setting them to 0.

---

**Running tests -**

1. With a value that meets condition

```
Numbers = np.array([123.6 , 123.6 ,  -123.6, 110.3748 ,  111.6992976, 102.3165566,  97.81462811])

Numbers[(Numbers<=0).cumsum(dtype=bool)] = 0

#array([123.6, 123.6,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ])
```

2. With no values meeting the condition

```
Numbers = np.array([123.6 , 123.6 ,  123.6, 110.3748 ,  111.6992976, 102.3165566,  97.81462811])

Numbers[(Numbers<=0).cumsum(dtype=bool)] = 0

#array([123.6 , 123.6 , 123.6 , 110.3748 ,111.6992976 , 102.3165566 ,  97.81462811])
```

Comment: I found out that the problem with the function is if none of the elements meets the criteria it just turns all the numbers into zeroes.

Comment: I ma de another issue about this if you could take a look I would appreciate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66233741/array-formatting-with-argmax-numpy-python

Comment: Updated my answer, the alternate thread as well

Comment: Does this work as you expect it? were you able to understand the logic behind it? do let me know.

Comment: @egeSelcuk, do let me know if this is also resolved from your side :)

Comment: Yes it works thank you, sorry for the late response