# Array formatting with argmax numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, sorting

I am having trouble with the `Numbers[(Numbers<=0).argmax():] = 0` function it is supposed to turn all the elements behind it into zeroes if the condition is met, however if the condition is not met it turns all the array elements into zeroes. How can i fix this issue. If the `Numbers<=0` condition is not met the array should not change.

Array with satisfying condition at -35.15610151:

```
Numbers = np.array([123.6,       123.6 ,       123.6,        110.3748,     111.6992976,
 102.3165566,   97.81462811 , 89.50038472 , 96.48141473 , 90.49956702,
  88.59907611 , 77.96718698,  61.51611052,  56.84088612,  55.36302309,
  54.69866681,  56.44902415 , 59.49727145,  42.12406819,  27.42276839,
  33.86711896,  32.10602877,  -35.15610151,  32.34361339 , 29.20628289])

Numbers[(Numbers<=0).argmax():] = 0
```

Output:

```
[123.6        123.6        123.6        110.3748     111.6992976
 102.3165566   97.81462811  89.50038472  96.48141473  90.49956702
  88.59907611  77.96718698  61.51611052  56.84088612  55.36302309
  54.69866681  56.44902415  59.49727145  42.12406819  27.42276839
  33.86711896  32.10602877   0.           0.           0.        ]
```

Array with no satisfying condition, turned -35.15610151 into +35.15610151:

```
Numbers = np.array([123.6,       123.6 ,       123.6,        110.3748,     111.6992976,
 102.3165566,   97.81462811 , 89.50038472 , 96.48141473 , 90.49956702,
  88.59907611 , 77.96718698,  61.51611052,  56.84088612,  55.36302309,
  54.69866681,  56.44902415 , 59.49727145,  42.12406819,  27.42276839,
  33.86711896,  32.10602877,  35.15610151,  32.34361339 , 29.20628289])

Numbers[(Numbers<=0).argmax():] = 0
```

Output:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0.]
```

Comment: Have you checked `(Numbers<=0).argmax()` by itself?  If that isn't right, the larger expression won't be either.

Comment: `np.ones(3, bool).argmax()` is 0, the first `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these 2 methods, one is in place assignment to the NumPy view and the other creates a fresh array to be assigned to another variable -

```
#Method 1 (Inplace assignment)
Numbers[(Numbers<=0).cumsum(dtype=bool)] = 0
```

*Or,*

```
#Method 2 (Not inplace)
np.where(~(Numbers<=0).cumsum(dtype=bool), Numbers, 0)
```

*Or,*

```
#As an excellent suggestion by Mad Physicist!
Numbers[np.logical_or.accumulate(Numbers >= 0)] = 0
```

**Explanation -**

1. The bool array that returns `[F, F, F, T, F, F, F]` can be seen as an array of 1s and 0s. Doing a cumsum ends up propogating the first T to the subsequent elements.
2. This, therefore, turns the array as `[F, F, F, T, T, T, T]` which can now be used with just `boolean indexing` and set the view to 0 OR `np.where` to fetch original elements or 0 based on reversing the boolean with `~`
3. Advantage here is that if your array is just composed of False, meaning no element meets the condition, it just returns the original `Numbers` itself, instead of setting them to 0.

---

**Running tests -**

1. With a value that meets condition

```
Numbers = np.array([123.6 , 123.6 ,  -123.6, 110.3748 ,  111.6992976, 102.3165566,  97.81462811])

Numbers[(Numbers<=0).cumsum(dtype=bool)] = 0

#array([123.6, 123.6,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ])
```

2. With no values meeting the condition

```
Numbers = np.array([123.6 , 123.6 ,  123.6, 110.3748 ,  111.6992976, 102.3165566,  97.81462811])

Numbers[(Numbers<=0).cumsum(dtype=bool)] = 0

#array([123.6 , 123.6 , 123.6 , 110.3748 ,111.6992976 , 102.3165566 ,  97.81462811])
```

---

**EDIT:** New scenario as requested

```
Numbers1 = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5])
Numbers2 = np.array([1,2,-3,4,5])

Numbers2 = np.where(~(Numbers2<=0).cumsum().astype(bool), Numbers1, 0)
Numbers2
```

```
array([1.1, 2.2, 0. , 0. , 0. ])
```

Comment: More efficiently, `n[np.logical_or.accumulate(n >= 0)] = 0`

Comment: Thank you that works. Is there a way I could implement this so that  it also scans another array like `np.where(~(Numbers2<=0).cumsum().astype(bool), Numbers, 0)` where `Numbers2` is another array like `Numbers` with the same length  but for the numbers below 0 it just modifies `Numbers` elements to 0. 
`

Comment: Wouldnt the same code work for that as well? `np.where(~(Numbers2<=0).cumsum().astype(bool), Numbers, 0)`?

Comment: Working for me. I have edited my answer do check.

Comment: Thank you i did a stupid mistake thank you it works

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `if` for this, it represents the intention quite well, and is easy to understand:

```
smaller_equal_zero = Numbers <= 0
if smaller_equal_zero.any():
    Numbers[smaller_equal_zero.argmax():] = 0
```

With Python 3.8+ you can use an assignment expression in the `if`:

```
if (smaller_equal_zero := Numbers <= 0).any():
    Numbers[smaller_equal_zero.argmax():] = 0
```